How can I get the information of a mic using a USB to 3.5mm adapter?
My current project has a requirement to obtain the name of the currently connected external microphone device. Since the intended microphone uses a 3.5mm jack, I need to connect it through a USB to 3.5mm adapter.
I have used AudioManager and UsbManager,
fun getExternalMicrophoneName(audioManager: AudioManager): String? {
    val devices = audioManager.getDevices(AudioManager.GET_DEVICES_INPUTS)
    for (device in devices) {
        if (device.type == AudioDeviceInfo.TYPE_USB_HEADSET) {
            return device.productName.toString()
        }
    }
    return null
}

UsbManager
fun getExternalUsbMicrophoneName(audioManager: AudioManager): String? {
    val usbManager = getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE) as UsbManager
    val devices = usbManager.deviceList
    for (device in devices.values) {
            return device.productName.toString()
    }
    return null
}

but the device information I get seems to be that of the adapter.
How can I get the microphone information, such as its name?
Thanks.

The name of the 3.5 mm microphone? its just a simple  TRS/TRRS connection (3 or 4 wires). If you have a USB-C microphone device you may get different info.

The best you can get is the name of hte USB to 3.5mm adapter. The 3.5mm microphone itself has no way to tell you its name because it just transmit analog sound waveform signal. It doesn't have a digital communication like USB HID, which encapsulate different kinds of information.

NeilLin I have posted an answer, hope it's helpful. Consider giving your feedback.

You can try getting information from below code :
Getting USB name :
fun getExternalMicrophoneName(audioManager: AudioManager, usbManager: UsbManager): String? {
    val audioName = getExternalMicrophoneName(audioManager)
    val usbName = getExternalUsbMicrophoneName(usbManager)

    return usbName ?: audioName
}

Getting device name :
fun getExternalUsbMicrophoneName(usbManager: UsbManager): String? {
    val devices = usbManager.deviceList.values
    for (device in devices) {
        if (device.deviceClass == UsbDevice.CLASS_AUDIO && device.deviceSubclass == UsbDevice.SUBCLASS_AUDIO_UNDEFINED) {
            // Microphone category identified (might not be exact)
            return device.productName.toString()
        }
    }
    return null
}

Part 2
Unfortunately, directly accessing microphone information using a USB-to-3.5mm adapter in Android code is restricted.
While the adapter module does not have an identifier or specific information, it is effective. Sometimes the retrieved information can pertain solely to the adapter and not to the microphone connected to it.
Alternatively :
1. Check for Microphone Permission:
Ask from the user for RECORD_AUDIO permission.
If the permission is granted then it means that there exists a microphone (though it does not tell details about that microphone).
2. Audio Recording Test:
The last coding example is an attempt to record a short audio clip using AudioRecord.
If the recording is successful, it implies that a microphone is connected (still can be any microphone and not specifically USB).
3. Use Existing APIs:
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context. AUDIO_SERVICE);
int devices = audioManager. getDevices(AudioManager. GET_DEVICES_INPUTS);

But this will only give information like ‘USB Headset’, instead of giving information about the microphone name.

Note:

It is possible that some USB microphones contain proprietary ways of retrieving data from such devices. It may also be possible to look into documentation provided by the respective manufacturers of the components, yet compatibility might not be guaranteed.

Consider using third-party libraries that state that they access the USB device information frequently use reflection or undocumented APIs, more often which are unstable and stop working after some update to the Android platform.


